# SOAP The root element for the request could not be determined

Tags: soap

I'm getting the following error when I try and post some SOAP requests:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
 xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soap:Body>
    <soap:Fault>
        <soap:Code>
            <soap:Value>soap:Receiver</soap:Value>
        </soap:Code>
        <soap:Reason>
            <soap:Text>The root element for the request could not be determined. When RoutingStyle is set to RequestElement, SoapExtensions configured via an attribute on the method cannot modify the request stream before it is read. The extension must be configured via the SoapExtensionTypes element in web.config or the request must arrive at the server as clear text.</soap:Text>
        </soap:Reason>
    </soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
```

I'm using

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
  xmlns:m="http://test.#######.co.uk/ws-b/>
    <soapenv:Body>
     <hs:logon>
       <hs:username>USER</m:username>
       <hs:password>pass123</m:password>
    </hs:logon>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

However, I can get some request to work using messages of a similar format. What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

"hs" namespace doesn't seem to be declared. Also you closing tags are with different namespace than openings. Can you try:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
  xmlns:hs="http://test.#######.co.uk/ws-b/">
    <soapenv:Body>
     <hs:logon>
       <hs:username>USER</hs:username>
       <hs:password>pass123</hs:password>
    </hs:logon>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: And he's missing a closing quote around the `xmlns:hs` namespace, among other problems.

Comment: I'd missed the closing tag namespaces - which I've corrected and added the closing quote on the name space - but I'm still getting the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I finally got to work:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <Body>
        <logon xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <username>user</username>
            <password>password</password>

        </logon>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```